# Store time in a session

Tags: php, session, time, refresh

I have a code that works just fine but I have a few questions about it. I don't understand the logic of something. The code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['t0'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['t0']=time();
    echo $_SESSION['t0']."if<br />"; //why this is never printed?
}
else 
{

    if(time()>=($_SESSION['t0']+3))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['t0']."else-ul";
        $culoare="rgb(".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).",".rand(0,255).")";
        $_SESSION['t0']=time(); 
    }

}
?>
```

The questions would be:
1. Why the first echo is never printed?
2. Why (time()>=($_SESSION['t0']+3)) isn't always true since $_SESSION['t0'] is updated every second because of session[t0]=time() ?

Thank you!

Comment: `since $_SESSION['t0'] is updated every second` I think there's a slight misunderstanding here. do you reload your page every second? php scripts run once, send output if any and then stop executing. also the first echo is not displaying because the condition is never true. (at least not before you call `session_unset()` and/or `session_destroy()`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now what was the logic behind this! Ty all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First echo statement does get executed, but it happens only on **very first time**. Once you had your session started value for `$_SESSION['t0']` is always set, so the if condition will always return false.
2. `time()>=($_SESSION['t0']+3)` condition is true when 3 seconds has passed after execution of the code. So if you reload your page after 2 seconds it will not get executed.